# How long an inactive Activity will store in memory and able to restore from savedInstanceState?

Tags: android

I was wondering, is there a way to know roughly how long an inactive `Activity` will stay in memory, and able to restore from `savedInstanceState`?

The reason is that, for every `Activity`, I am assigning them an unique uuid, to accessing temporary persistence data from DB.

When user performs "proper" quit (By pressing back button), my system knows that the associated uuid is no longer being used, and able to clean up all associated data.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        // Perform uuid DB clean up and all associated data.
    }
}
```

However, when user put the `Activity` inactive state by performing HOME button place, we **cannot** just remove the uuid from DB.

As, there is a possibility that user can perform `Activity` restore at any time point. The uuid can be retrieved from `savedInstanceState`, and being reused again.

However, we must some how clean up the DB at some time. If not, the DB just grow infinity.

Our plan is assigning a timestamp for the uuid. Say, if the uuid is not being used within 3 days, we assume it is no longer associated with any **active** `Activity`, or any **restore-able** `Activity`. We can then safetly clear it out from DB.

I was wondering, is there a way/ or documentation to know, how long an inactive Activity will store in memory and able to restore from savedInstanceState? With such information, we can know how long we should wait, before marking an uuid as expired.

p/s

We do not save our data in `savedInstanceState`, as the size of our data is rather dynamic. It ranges from few kilo bytes to few mega bytes. Currently, we are encountering `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` for some cases.

Comment: Android holds activities as long as it's possible. Only one condition for this flow is memory usage. Your active activity can be killed in any time in background and foreground on rotate for example. Why you use DB for temporary/unsaved data? You can use ViewModel for it or savedInstanceState if your data is parcelable.

Comment: See our update on why we do not use `savedInstanceState`. `ViewModel` will not solved the problem, as it is unable to handle case for Activity recreation (Not configuration change)

Comment: It could be good idea to clear cacheable data when you're creating new one. So you will have one piece of data for each type.